# Rails form_for checkbox validation without record in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to create an User register form that has to accept a set of terms and condition, but I don't know how to use the value of the checkbox to verify if it was clicked(server side).

I've tried to use this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#acceptance, but so far I haven't achieved anything.

I have `validates :terms_of_service, acceptance: { accept: '1' }` in my User.rb and in my form `<%= f.check_box :terms_of_service,:value =>'0',:class =>"hidden", :id =>"t_and_c" %>`, but I can submit the form without clicking on it. What am I doing wrong? If I have to post anything else to make the question easier to understand let me know.

Answer (score 0):

In your form the check box should return true when they click it.

In your form you just specify if the checkbox is checked or not:

```
<%= f.check_box :terms_of_service %> Accept Terms of Services
check_box(object_name, method, options = {}, checked_value = "1", unchecked_value = "0")
```

In your controller you just save what is returned from the form:

```
#you whitelist the parameter together with all the other params you have
 def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:terms_of_services)
 end

#You create your user as usual
def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
end
```

In you migration, I would add a default option for :terms_of_services to make it more explicit.

```
class AddTermsOfServicesToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :terms_of_services, :boolean, default: false
  end
end
```

EDIT

If you don't create a column in your User model, you don't have a way to work with terms of services on the server side. You CAN work with terms_of_servies on your client side only if you like without creating a column. This is how you could do that:

Create a checkbox without the Rails check_box helper (because it would require an object that you don't have since you have no column in the database)

```
  <input type="checkbox" id="cbox1" value="accepted" onchange='enableSubmitTag(this)'>
  <label for="cbox1">Accept Terms of Services</label>
```

Disable the Submit button by default

```
<%= f.submit "Create", class: "btn btn-primary", id: "submit_button", disabled: true%>
```

When they click the terms of services checkbox, enable the submit button again.

```
function enableSubmitTag(element) {
  if(element.checked){
    document.getElementById('submit_button').disabled = false; 
  } else {
    document.getElementById('submit_button').disabled = true;
  };
};
```

If you store :terms_of_services in your table, you can validate it on your server side too. You can use all the javascript. You just have to change the checkbox:

```
<%= f.check_box :terms_of_service, :onchange => 'enableSubmitTag(this)'  %> Accept Terms of Services
```

Comment: I updated my answer. I would also set the default value for :terms_of_services to false in your schema. That way the user explicitly has to change it to true.

Comment: I know how to use it if I put is as a column in my table. I wanted to check how it s possible to try it without.

Comment: You are talking about the client side then not the server side. You want to stop the form from submitting if it is unchecked ? In which case you have to use javascript. The validation in your model just prevents the record from being saved it doesn't stop the form from being submitted.

Comment: I'm talking about the server side. I saw somewhere that the `terms_of_service` verification can be achieve without having a column present in the table.

Comment: If you have no column on your table, you can't work with it on your server side but you can use pure javascript or a combination. The biggest issue without the column you can't validate that the terms of services was clicked. If the user disables javascript or changes it manually, he can bypass the javascript.

Comment: That was the point of the whole question. Look at the link I posted. It can work without.

Answer (score 0):

Model should have:

```
validates :terms_of_service, acceptance: true
```

Form should have:

```
<%= form_for :user, url: users_path do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= f.label :terms_of_service %><br>
  <%= f.check_box :terms_of_service %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

and Rails should do everything else for you.